# How to get the correct object in an nested array in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I use Axios to display a JSON data and I have succeeded. But I want to show an object based on date and time, it shows now all data and I need to filter it.

So I want to look at today's date and show the object based on that, so I want to show the next upcoming event. (24/05/2020)

What I currently have:

Json:

```
{
    "doc": [
        {
            "data": {
                "events": {
                    "18807612": {
                        "_dt": {
                            "_doc": "time",
                            "time": "18:45",
                            "date": "14/05/20",
                            "tz": "UTC",
                            "tzoffset": 0,
                            "uts": 1566067500
                        },
                        "week": 33,
                        "teams": {
                            "home": {
                                "name": "name 1",
                                "mediumname": "name1",
                                "uid": 3014
                            },
                            "away": {
                                "name": "name 2",
                                "mediumname": "name 2",
                                "uid": 3020
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "18807618": {
                        "_dt": {
                            "_doc": "time",
                            "time": "18:45",
                            "date": "24/05/20",
                            "tz": "UTC",
                            "tzoffset": 0,
                            "uts": 1566067500
                        },
                        "week": 33,
                        "teams": {
                            "home": {
                                "name": "name 1",
                                "mediumname": "name1",
                                "uid": 3014
                            },
                            "away": {
                                "name": "name 2",
                                "mediumname": "name2",
                                "uid": 3020
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Store:

```
async loadPosts({ commit }) {
    // Define urls pages
    const urlEvents = 'http://api.example.com/302020';

    // Set pages
    const [
      responseEvents
    ] = await Promise.all([
      // Responses pages
      this.$axios.get(urlEvents)
    ]);

    // variables pages
    this.events = responseEvents.data.doc[0].data.events

    // mutations pages
    commit('SET_EVENTS', this.events)
  }
},

mutations: {
  SET_EVENTS (state, events) {
    state.events = events;
  }
}
```

And to show the data I use this:

```
import {mapState} from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: 'NextMatch',
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('loadPosts')
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState([
      'events'
    ])
  }
}

<h1>{{events}}</h1>
```

But this shows all data, and what I try to get is the first upcoming event for the object with the `"uid": 3014`.

So I want to show the date, time and names of the home and away team.

How can I get the correct data by filtering the data?

Comment: i can't see where `fixtures` comes from, but presumably you should do something like `fixtures.doc.data.events.find(x => x.teams.home.uid === 3014)` and probably put this in a computed property rather than directly in the template

Comment: fixtures must be events, I edited my message.

Comment: Do you have an example for how to use this in an computed property?

Comment: Sure, i described it in the answer I left.  Something similar to that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this or similar to this should work:

In your Vue component's `<template>`:

```
`<h1>{{selectedEvent._dt.date}}</h1>`
```

In your Vue component's `<script>`:

```
    props: {
        eventID: {
          type: Number,
          default: 3014
        },
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapState([
        'events'
      ]),
      eventsArr(){
        if (!this.events) return {} //make sure Object.entries gets object.
        return Object.entries(this.events)
      },
      selectedEvent(){
        const selectedArr = this.eventsArr.find(([eID, e]) => e.teams.home.uid === this.eventID)
        return selectedArr[1]
      } 
    }
```

Comment: this doesn't work bro. maybe because using mapState in the controller? See my first message.

Comment: I get `this.events.find is not a function`

Comment: Oh i see -- `events` is not an array, it is an object.  So we have to convert it to an array (using something like `Object.entries()`) to use `.find` on it.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: I get it by adding this:
Will try your solution.

`const myData = Object.keys(this.events).map(key => this.events[key]);`

Comment: it can be done either way, but the 2nd way is more succinct, if your logic is simple enough to fit in 1 line.  Both `Object.keys()` and `Object.entries()` can probably be made to work.

Comment: Yes that works, but this gets the first object. But I need to get the most recent object. So if today is 24/5/2020 I need to get the first upcoming event. How can I do that? .find is stopping with searching when it find something..

Comment: Well, that's really getting into a different question now, but I would do something like instead of `.find` use `.reduce` and, as .reduce iterates, keep updating the reduce "accumulator's" value to the current element's value if a more recent event is found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214543/discussion-between-can-and-cato-minor).

Comment: im sorry, im out of time at this point, but i wish u all the best with your progress on this :).  in general, i would just read up on functional programming in JS a little more.

Comment: Thanks @Cato Minor. Found a way to do.